# Page not found (Slim Framework)

Tags: php, slim

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../src/config/db_standings.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

require '../src/routes/ppg.php';

require '../src/routes/standings.php';

$app->run();
```

So this is my `index.php` file and I don't understand why is it behaving the way that it only loads the last required route. In this case only `standings.php`. Whatever route I add last it only loads the last route and other pages are not found. What am I doing wrong?

standings.php

```
<?php

Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/api/standings', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM standings";

    try {
        $db = new db_standings();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $standings = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;

        $json = json_encode($standings, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

        echo($json);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

ppg.php

```
<?php

Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/api/ppg', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    echo 'BANANAS';
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `index.php` you are creating Slim application instance and put it in `$app` variable:

```
<?php

$app = new \Slim\App; # This is new Slim app contained in $app variable

// executing code of standings.php...
// executing code of ppg.php...

$app->run(); # Here you run the application that is contained in $app variable.
```

But you do the same thing in each included file: `standings.php` and `ppg.php`.

So, when you include `standings.php`, you overwrite content of the `$app` variable, add routes that are declared in the file.

Then you include `ppg.php` that overwrites `$app` instance (and, consequently, the routes that had been declared) and appends its routes.

When the flow of execution returns to `index.php`, it runs `$app->run()` and that `$app` happens to be the one created in the last file included.

Thus to fix the problem, simply remove this line

```
$app = new \Slim\App;
```

from all files but `index.php`.

**UPDATE**

In comments you wrote

> After removing the unnecessary and changing JSON output method I get
>   "Slim Application Error - sorry for the temporary inconvenience"

Okay, the reason for that is because you're doing it wrong, excuse me for being too harsh.

In essence, Slim application is a set of callbacks appended to specific routes.

Generally each callback accepts two arguments: request and response object, and each migh (or might not for some reason) change request and response to whatever you want. All callbacks are invoked one after another, in a chain.

The rule is simple: *any callback should return response object in the end*. And that response may be anything: html document, json data, a file - whatever can be returned in HTTP response.

Therefore in your Slim application if you're doning something like

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

or

```
echo $jsonString;
```

then you're doing it wrong. Instead of setting response header and outputting JSON directly, you should *build Response object that has that header and contains your data in body*. Slim is excellent at that, take a look (I've simplified your code a bit for better abstraction):

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Append callback to a route: note request response arugments.
$app->get('/api/standings', function(Request $request, Response $response) {

    $standingsRepository = new \StandingsRepository;

    $standings = $standingsRepository->getAll();

    if ($standings) {
    // Return response object
        return $response->withJson($standings);
    } else {
        // Or pass to another callback: note request and response
    return new \Slim\Exception\NotFoundException($request, $response);
    }

});
```

Here we used `withJson` method of `Response` object. This sets `application/json` header to your response and puts in body whatever you pass as argument. In our case it's value of $standings variable (I assume it's an array of objects).

I hope I made things a bit more clear for you. I strongly suggest to read [framework documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/), it will take you one evening and two cups of coffee and save you so much time.

Comment: After removing the unnecessary and changing JSON output method I get "Slim Application Error - sorry for the temporary inconvenience"

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the original question, but I've updated the answer as best as I could. Consider asking a different question.

Comment: thank you for the well explanation about overwriting $app in each file

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Georgy Ivanov in the below answer you have to remove following block from standings.php and ppg.php:

```
Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;
```

In addition, since your intention is to output a JSON response you can simply to that by using Slim's withJson() method:

```
return $response->withJson($standings);
```

refer to this https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#returning-json

Comment: After removing the unnecessary and changing JSON output method I get "Slim Application Error - sorry for the temporary inconvenience"